# Toggle. (one at a time)

Tags: javascript, html, css

### Heading

I can't seem to get my program to run properly. I am suppose to have the program run one question at a time. Meaning if I click on one question the other will disappear. I have tried many things but when I click on all the questions all the answer show.

My code:

faqs.js file

```
"use strict";
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };

// the event handler for the click event of each h2 element
var toggle = function() {
var h2 = this;                    // clicked h2 tag     
var div = h2.nextElementSibling;  // h2 tag's sibling div tag

// toggle plus and minus image in h2 elements by adding or removing a class
if (h2.hasAttribute("class")) { 
    h2.removeAttribute("class");    
} else { 
    h2.setAttribute("class", "minus"); 
}

// toggle div visibility by adding or removing a class
if (div.hasAttribute("class")) { 
    div.removeAttribute("class");
} else { 
    div.setAttribute("class", "open"); 
  } 
};

window.onload = function() {
// get the h2 tags
 var faqs = $("faqs");
 var h2Elements = faqs.getElementsByTagName("h2");

 // attach event handler for each h2 tag        
 for (var i = 0; i < h2Elements.length; i++ ) {
    h2Elements[i].onclick = toggle;
}
  // set focus on first h2 tag's <a> tag
  h2Elements[0].firstChild.focus();       
};
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>FAQs</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <script src="faqs.js"></script>       
</head>

<body>
  <main id="faqs">
    <h1>JavaScript FAQs</h1>
    <h2><a href="#" >What is JavaScript?</a></h2>
    <div>
        <p>JavaScript is a is a browser-based programming language 
           that makes web pages more responsive and saves round trips to the 
  server.
        </p>
    </div>
    <h2><a href="#">What is jQuery?</a></h2>
    <div>
        <p>jQuery is a library of the JavaScript functions that you're most 
 likely 
           to need as you develop websites.
        </p>
    </div>
    <h2><a href="#">Why is jQuery becoming so popular?</a></h2>
    <div>
        <p>Three reasons:</p>
        <ul>
            <li>It's free.</li>
            <li>It lets you get more done in less time.</li>
            <li>All of its functions are cross-browser compatible.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

---

I also not sure if I should change something in the CSS file.

main.css

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
 body {
 font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 87.5%;
 width: 650px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: 3px solid blue;
 padding: 15px 25px;
}
h1 { 
  font-size: 150%;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 120%;
  padding: .25em 0 .25em 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url(images/plus.png) no-repeat left center;
}
h2.minus {
   background: url(images/minus.png) no-repeat left center;
}
a {
   color: black;
   text-decoration: none; 
}
a:focus, a:hover { 
   color: blue; 
}
div {
   display: none;
}
div.open {
   display: block;
}
ul {
   padding-left: 45px;
}
li {
  padding-bottom: .25em;
}
p {
  padding-bottom: .25em;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check to see if your `.minus` and `.open` classes exist within your toggle function and remove them before applying them to the new active item. Here's a working [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/4fow7jy4/45/):

```
"use strict";
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };

// the event handler for the click event of each h2 element
var toggle = function() {
    var h2 = this;                    // clicked h2 tag     
    var div = h2.nextElementSibling;  // h2 tag's sibling div tag

    // toggle plus and minus image in h2 elements by adding or removing a class
    if (h2.hasAttribute("class")) { 
        h2.removeAttribute("class");    
    } else {
        var activeHeader = document.getElementsByClassName("minus");
        if(activeHeader.length) {
            activeHeader[0].removeAttribute("class");;
        }
        h2.setAttribute("class", "minus"); 
    }

    // toggle div visibility by adding or removing a class
    if (div.hasAttribute("class")) { 
        div.removeAttribute("class");
    } else {
        var activePanel = document.getElementsByClassName("open");
        if(activePanel.length) {
            activePanel[0].removeAttribute("class");;
        }
        div.setAttribute("class", "open"); 
    } 
};

window.onload = function() {
    // get the h2 tags
    var faqs = $("faqs");
    var h2Elements = faqs.getElementsByTagName("h2");

    // attach event handler for each h2 tag        
    for (var i = 0; i < h2Elements.length; i++ ) {
        h2Elements[i].onclick = toggle;
    }
    // set focus on first h2 tag's <a> tag
    h2Elements[0].firstChild.focus();       
};
```

The added parts are:

```
var activeHeader = document.getElementsByClassName("minus");
if(activeHeader.length) {
    activeHeader[0].removeAttribute("class");;
}
```

and:

```
var activePanel = document.getElementsByClassName("open");
if(activePanel.length) {
    activePanel[0].removeAttribute("class");;
}
```